# How does C++ function template specialization work?

Tags: c++, templates, template-function

I am reading [C++ Primer (5th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113), 16.5, Defining a Function Template Specialization, and confused about the example given by author, let's see the following template function:

```
template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&);
```

and its specialization version:

```
template <>
int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2)
{
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
```

Type of `T` will be `const char *`, but I don't think the function could be the specialization version of the template function, because I think `const char* const &p1` can only be the specialization of `T const &` but `const T &`, I know I'm wrong, but I want to know why I am wrong.

***Edit:***

One thing to emphasize, if I invoke `compare("hi", "mom")`, it won't compile, that is to say, `template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&)` can not be initialized to `int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2)`, I know `T` will be initialized with `char[3]` or `char[4]`, but now that this won't compile, why won't compiler ignore this kind of initialization but choose one that will compile?

Comment: There is no difference between `const T` and `T const`.  Does that resolve your confusion?

Comment: So, `const T &` has no difference with `T const &`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `const T` and `T const` mean exactly the same thing.  Therefore `const T &` and `T const &` mean exactly the same thing.

It couldn't really be any other way, because references can never be changed to refer to something else (they are not "reseatable").  If you read `T const &` as "a reference which cannot be changed to refer to a different T", that's incorrect.  It is "a reference to a T, which cannot be used to modify that T (and as with all references, cannot be changed to refer to a different T)."

Comment: But if I invoke `compare("hi", "mom");`, why can't `template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&);` be initialized with `int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2)`? It won't compile.

Comment: I have updated my question, you can refer to it now, thanks.

Comment: @cong: The compiler won't use the `const char*` specialization because it is a worse match than the one using the array types (`char[4]` and `char[3]`).  You might wish it would choose to use the `const char*` version because the `T` version doesn't compile, but that's not how C++ works--it tries to compile with the best-matching types, and if that fails it stops trying.

Answer (score 2):

`const` can be either before or after a type, except for a pointer type, where it must be on the right side.

Now the tricky part here is, that `T` in your example is set to `const char*`, which is a pointer type (*pointer to a `const char`*). The template says that `T` has to be `const`, and since it's a pointer type the `const` in the specialization has to be put after the type, hence you get `const char* const`.

It becomes a bit more clear when reading it aloud from right to left:

*"a const pointer to a char that is const"*

**//Edit:**

Why can't you call `compare("hi", "mom");`? Because those char arrays are treated as different types by your compiler (`char[3]` and `char[4]`), but the template specifies both parameters to be the same type.

This will match the template, however it will not match your specialization (as `T` is now `char[2]`):

```
compare("a", "b");
```

This works and uses your specialized method:

```
const char * hi = "hi";
const char * mom = "mom";
compare(hi, mom);
```

**//Edit2:**

*"I know T will be initialized with char[3] or char[4], [...] why won't compiler ignore this kind of initialization but choose one that will compile?"*

Because C++ is a strongly typed language. The compiler doesn't do guess work for you, it takes the types at face value. If they don't match, they don't match. It's your job as developer to do it right.

Comment: If I invoke `compare("hi", "mom");`, there is a compile error, `template <typename T> int compare(const T&, const T&);` can not be initialized to `int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2)`, why?

Comment: @cong I've edited my answer, but please don't use comments to ask questions. Update your question instead, or ask a new one if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question, you can refer to it now.